# Regex to Match Multiple Words In Different Order

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

string sample: "universal studios japan"

How do i make so that it matches with "japan universal studios" 
AND also with "japan univer"

Right now I'm using the following to regex :

```
^(?=.*\bjapan\b)(?=.*\buniversal\b)(?=.*\bstudios\b)
```

which works but

```
^(?=.*\bjapan\b)(?=.*\buniver\b)
```

does not work. It has to be a complete match for the second word..

`^(?=.*\bjapan\b)(?=.*\buniversal\b)` would work..

What changes do i need to make?

Comment: Just drop the word boundary after `univer`? If that's not enough, can you clarify with more examples?

Comment: oh you're right!

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.*\bjapan\b)(?=.*\buniver(?:sal)?\b)
```

You can make `sal` optional.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wDUC7j/1